# «Старый-новый президент» — можно так написать?

Tags: орфография

Старый-новый президент. Он переизбирался пять раз. Поэтому его называют "старый-новый". Как это слово написать? Дефис, кавычки нужны?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В отношении правописания вам ответили. Я за вариант без дефиса. 
Чтобы разобраться, почему, лучше начать со второй части вопроса, ответа на который здесь пока нет.

Итак. "Старый новый президент" (и как вариант - "Новый Старый") это человек, вступивший в должность, в данном случае - президента, повторно. Он новый потому, что он выиграл выборы только что, но поскольку он и до того был, значит он "повторный", "не новый", т.е. **Старый "Новый Президент"**. В такой конструкции (без кавычек, естественно) определения выступают как неоднородные, потому что первое относится не к одному определяемому слову, а ко всей конструкции "Новый Президент". Ну или по крайней мере как некоторый аналог неоднородных определений: они характеризуют объект с разных сторон. 
В такой конструкции ни дефис, ни запятая не нужны.

Могу добавить, что такая "игра антагонизмов" - довольно распространенный и выразительный прием. Сравните: "Плохой хороший человек" (фильм Хейфица по повести Чехова), "Старый Новый год" (эти примеры вам уже приводили), "Богатая бедная страна" (о странах, богатых ресурсами, но экономически неразвитых) и проч.

Answer (score 3):

Здесь нет объединения сущностей, действующих порознь (для таких случаев нужен дефис), поэтому раздельное написание: президент одновременно и старый, и новый. Вспомним написание названий двух фильмов: "Старый Новый год" и "Плохой хороший человек".

Comment: В приведенных вами примерах, Александр, слова ''Старый'' и "Плохой'' представляют собой неоднородные определения. А в словосочетании ''старый-новый'' нет неоднородных определений. суть в том, что президент одновременно и старый и новый. Здесь парные сочетания.

Comment: Серж, как раз здесь они не парные. См. мой ответ. Он с **разных сторон** новый и старый. Отнюдь не просто "одновременно".

Answer (score 0):

Если вопрос касается только орфографической стороны, то в данном примере нужен дефис. Хотя такое словосочетание неудачное.

***Не являются однородными членами предложения и не разделяются запятой, а соединяются дефисом:***

> парные сочетания антонимического характера: сформулировать вопросы-ответы; расширился экспорт-импорт; условия купли-продажи; отмечать приход-расход; приём-выдача книг; твёрдость-мягкость согласных; бегать вверх-вниз; двигаться вперёд-назад;

См.: Справочник по пунтктуации. Розенталь. Д.Э.